# PyInstaller has a PIL directory, but the exe file throws an error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'"

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pyinstaller

I wrote a program, that has line "from PIL import ImageTk, Image".
I need to make an exe file from my .py file.

Pyinstaller has a PIL folder in its directory, but the program still throws an error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'".

At first, I tried just "pyinstaller --onefile kryptocalc.py".
That error occurs.

Then with --hidden-import=PIL.
Error still occurs.

With --add-data="my path to PIL directory":PIL --hidden-import=PIL.
Still the same.

Folder with PIL directory appeared in dist, but the error didn't disappear.
PIL directory is located in the same folder as .py file.

Comment: Are you using any virtual environment? In that case you should activate the virtual environment before packaging. You are saying that you have PIL folder in the same folder as the .py file. I don't think you can import PIL like that. If you want to import PIL , make sure you have it installed in your environment using `pip install pillow`.

Comment: yes, and pillow is installed